# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke ".repository.updatePassword.updtPassword because clientJsonWebTokenValidation.upPassword is null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have written the service class as follows -

```
@Service
public class clientJsonWebTokenValidation {
    
    @Autowired
    private static updatePassword upPassword;
```

later in the program I have called the JpaRepository method by supplying necessary parameters as follows in this program , where the exception is arising .

```
    upPassword.updtPassword(strClientUsername,strNewPasswordToReset);
```

And the JpaRepository implementation is as follows

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.erecruitment.app.model.user;
@Repository
public interface updatePassword extends JpaRepository<user, Long>{
    
    public String nativeQuery="UPDATE user SET password='?' WHERE username='?'";
    
    @Query(value=nativeQuery,nativeQuery=true)
    boolean updtPassword(String strUsernameOfWhichPasswordToUpdate,String 
    strPasswordToBeUpdated);    
}
```

Also user pojo is as follows -

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class user {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @JsonProperty("username")
    @Column(name="username")
     private String username;
    
    @JsonProperty("password")
    @Column(name="password")
     private String password;
    
    public user() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    

    public user(String username, String password) {
        super();
    
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }


    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }


    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }


    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

And the exception is
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.er.app.repository.updatePassword.updtPassword(String, String)" because "com.er.app.service.clientJsonWebTokenValidation.upPassword" is null

How to resolve this exception ? Any alternative solution is also fine .Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

Dependency Injection does not work on static fields.

```
@Autowired
private static updatePassword upPassword;
```

Remove the static keyword:

```
@Autowired
private updatePassword upPassword;
```

Some notes:

- @Repository is not necessary on interfaces that extend JpaRepository.
- In Java we write classes/interfaces starting with an uppercase letter